# How to give path based permission to a specific group in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command

I'm stuck into something complex which makes me think that this scenario is not possible. Anyway here's the scenario:

Say my directory structure is like this:
    /var/www/dir1/dir2/dir3

```
/var is owned by root
/var/www/dir1/ is owned by group1
/var/www/dir1/dir2 is owned by group2
```

the problem i have is that i want to allow dir2/ group users to have only access to this directory and I don't want them to have access to the upper directories.

I tried changing the chmod of dir1/ to 711 but it then restricts the group2 users.

Is there any way to allow group2 users access the dir2/ but not any parent directories?

If so, please explain.

Waiting for response..
Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for chroot. See for example this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html to get a basic idea of it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. According to my understanding, I'll have to change many things like copying directories and stuff but I wanted to give access to the group only to a specific directory and nothing else. Is chroot the only solution for it? Thanks

Comment: If you want them to be *jailed* in that specific directory, yes. Otherwise they will be able to go through other dirs.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Please write your answer in the answer box and I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments:

You are looking for chroot. See for example this [cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html](http://cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html) to get a basic idea of it

Then we commented:

> According to my understanding, I'll have to change many things like
>   copying directories and stuff but I wanted to give access to the group
>   only to a specific directory and nothing else. Is chroot the only
>   solution for it?

And my view is that if you want them to be jailed in that specific directory, yes. Otherwise they will be able to go through other dirs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've approved your answer but I can't +1 it yet as I don't have much points.

Comment: No problem! It's more than enough. You'll be able to upvote once you reach 15 reputation http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up